# VC++ REGEX ANSI C equivalent

Tags: c++, c, regex

I have the following C++ code, works ok:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string str("mymail@yahoo.com;lslsls;myemail@gmail.com");
    std::tr1::regex rx("([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})");
    std::tr1::sregex_iterator first(str.begin(), str.end(), rx);
    std::tr1::sregex_iterator last;

    for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) 
    {
        std::cout << "[Email] => " << it->str(1) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

is there a simple way to earn this in C ANSI (*.cpp -> *.c) using native libraries? I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Do you want to translate that code into ANSI C?

Comment: Yes. Is there a simple way using native code/libraries for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: C doesn't support regex natively, but there are some libraries. I don't really know how to use them in VS10 because I've never used it but since it's just "regex.c" you can use it easily. ftp://ftp.mutt.org/mutt/regex.c